# shell: why [ -d ] returns true instead of false?

Tags: shell

As is told [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html), the command `[ -d FILE ]` is used to check whether a file is directory.

However, when we miss the `FILE` parameter in the expression, it still returns true.

Why? How does shell interpret this expression then?

Example should be straightforward enough :)

```shell
$ [ -d /tmp ]
$ echo $?          # prints 0
$ [ -d ]
$ echo $?          # why prints 0 as well?
```

Comment: If you use quotes for directory (`[ -d "" ]`) it returns 1 as you would expect.

Comment: @Phylogenesis thanks, actually I was reviewing a student's homework, and failed to explain why he should use "" here :)

Comment: @billybob: That's easily explained even if you don't know how `[ -d ]` behaves. `-d` tests whether its argument is a directory. It doesn't make much sense to use `-d` without an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It gets interpreted as `[ -n -d ]`. In other words, since you've only provided one argument `-d` gets treated as if it were any other string, and as you can read in [the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test):

> `-n STRING`
>     the length of `STRING` is nonzero
>
> `STRING`
>       equivalent to `-n STRING`

Answer (score 5):

`-d` is only treated as an operator if `[` receives 2 arguments. `[ -d`] is a one-argument form of the `[` command, which exits with 0 if its single argument is non-null. Since `-d` is a non-null string, it exits 0.

`[ -d "" ]`, on the other hand, is a two-argument form of the `[` command, with the two arguments "-d" and "". Now the first argument is treated as a primary operator that acts on the second argument.